# Updating @ElementCollection attributes with JPA QueryDSL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I want to remove a specific user ID from a field mapped with a collection table. How is this possible with a single QueryDSL JPA update statement?

What is need is something like this:

```
new JPAUpdateClause(getEntityManager(), sharing).where(sharing.key.eq(sharingKey))
                        .set(sharing.userIds, ***sharing.userIds - userId***).execute();
```

Mapped class:

```
public class Sharing {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "naturalid", unique = true)
    private String key;
    private int creatorUserId;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "pla_sharing2users", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "sid"))
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private Set<Integer> userIds;
...
}
```

Comment: I just realized that my question was stupid.

Comment: I realized that I should modify the entity objects and saving these changes back to the database instead of writing update statements.

Comment: Fair enough. That's usually a lot easier. It won't be as fast, but that often doesn't matter.